# XeLaTeX stops working after a few days

Tags: xetex, mac

I have recently (October) moved to a Mountain Lion-based laptop from Snow Leopard.  I find that if I have not rebooted within the last week or so, XeLaTeX will just die in the middle of a run.  The PDF output is empty.  If I give a full reboot to my laptop, it will be just fine for the next week or so.  Has anyone else had this problem and if so, is there a fix?

Comment: What kind of error does `xelatex` throw out? Care to elaborate on what "just die" means?

Comment: XeTeX uses a font cache and if it wasn't build before the compilation stops for a moment to build it. If you have a lot of fonts, it can take more than a minute! However, the log file should say more ...

Comment: Clarification:  It just dies.  The output stops and returns me to a command prompt.  There is no error message.  The log abruptly stops where XeLaTeX decided to stop.  You can insert the whole dead parrot sketch here.  I mean it's dead.  Were there an error message or something like that, it'd be easier to diagnose, so that's a huge piece of this puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confident this is not a general problem: I very rarely reboot my Mac (running 10.8), and XeTeX works fine. I guess the most obvious suspect would be as commented something to do with the system-dependent font hooks in XeTeX: that is likely to need expertise outside of the TeX area to solve so would be off-topic.

Comment: Test `XeTeX` installation at Terminal/commandline window with `xetex opentype-info` to get `opentype-info.pdf` on TeXLive distro